# Show that $\leq$ is transitive over the cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory, cardinals

$A, B, C$ are sets. I want to show $|A|\leq|B| \ \text{and} \ |B|\leq|C| \Longrightarrow |A|\leq|C|$.

I am confused as to how I would approach this, because the sets in this problem can be either finite or infinite.

Does anyone have a good way of approaching this problem? It seems like it isn't hard but I feel like I am overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $|A| \leq |B|$ there is an injection $f: A \to B$. If $|B| \leq |C|$ there is another injection $g: B \to C$. Now look at $g\circ f: A \to C$.

Comment: For finite sets this is obvious. I'm wondering, does this also hold for infinite sets?

Comment: Yes, it holds. ${}$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** The composition of two injections is an injection.

Answer (score 0):

$|A| \leq |B|$ if there is $f$ injective, $f: A \to B$.
But composition of two injective functions is an injection:
If $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ are injections then $g \circ f$ is an injection.
As $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$, and $g(x) = g(y) \implies x = y$, so:
$$g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \implies f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$$
Then, if $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |C| \implies |A| \leq |C|$.